# Laravel Excel Import - MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5.4, methodnotfound

In my Laravel Project i import data from Excel (.CSV). When i upload small count data (15 or 10) its imported, but upload more than 200 data its return  (1/1) **MethodNotAllowedHttpException**. i using **Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel** package to upload Data.

Controller Code :

```
 public function uploadleads(Request $request){


        $usersid = Auth::user()->id;

        if($request->hasFile('leads')){

            Excel::load($request->file('leads')->getRealPath(), function ($reader) use($usersid) {

                foreach ($reader->toArray() as $key => $row) {

                    $data['name'] = ucfirst($row['candidatename']);
                    $data['gender'] = ucfirst($row['gender']);
                    $data['mobile'] = $row['mobileno'];
                    $data['email'] = $row['email'];
                    $data['work_experience'] = $row['workexperience'];
                    $data['resume_title'] = $row['resumetitle'];
                    $data['current_location'] = $row['currentlocation'];
                    $data['preferred_location'] = $row['preferredlocation'];
                    $data['current_employer'] = $row['currentemployer'];
                    $data['current_designation'] = $row['currentdesignation'];
                    $data['annual_salary'] = $row['annualsalary'];
                    $data['ug_course'] = $row['ugcourse'];
                    $data['pg_coruse'] = $row['pgcourse'];
                    $data['post_pg_course'] = $row['postpgcourse'];
                    $data['leads_address'] = $row['address'];
                    $data['telephone'] = $row['telephone'];
                    $data['dateofbirth'] = $row['dateofbirth'];
                    $data['sourcefrom'] = $row['sourcefrom'];
                    $data['created_by'] = $usersid;

                $baseleadscounts=Baseleads::Where('mobile',$row['mobileno'])->OrWhere('email',$row['email'])->count();    

                $templeadscount=Templeads::Where('mobile',$row['mobileno'])->OrWhere('email',$row['email'])->count();   

                if(($baseleadscounts + $templeadscount) > 0){

                    DB::table('duplileads')->insert($data);

                } else {

                    if((preg_match('/(7|8|9)\d{9}/',$data['mobile'])) && ($row['gender'] == 'Male' || $row['gender'] == 'Female' || $row['gender'] == 'male' || $row['gender'] == 'female')){

                        DB::table('templeads')->insert($data);

                    } else {

                        DB::table('duplileads')->insert($data);

                    }

                }    

                }

            });
        }


    alert()->success('Data Imported Successfully.', 'Success!');

    return redirect('importreport');


    }
```

How to fix this Issue

Comment: check your route

Comment: Route::post('uploadleads','MasterController@uploadleads'); - route has no issue

Comment: echo something befoer post method and access the url like :- localhost:8000/uploadleads

Comment: like kunal is saying, this is usually a route issue (posing to a get) does your form validate?

Comment: Hello @Karthik did you find any solution? I am also facing the same issue. I think there is any hidden special character in the Excel file which is causing this error

Answer (score 0):

This error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` can be triggered when you are trying to submit a form with a `method='POST'` to a `Route::get` or vice versa.

Make sure that your route is correct and your form is using the appropriate method.

Comment: then how could this work when they are uploading a small file, if it was just a mismatched HTTP method? it wouldn't work under any circumstance if that was the case

Comment: One more thing, try to store your file to your server then load that file instead. See if it fixes the issue

Comment: No this is not the cause, I am also facing same issue. Please help, I have checked route and it is okay. File import is also working for small files.